# What is the difference between register_parameter and register_buffer in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Module's [parameters](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) get changed during training, that is, they are what is learnt during training of a neural network, but what is a [buffer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter)?

and is it learnt during neural network training?

Answer (score 60):

Pytorch [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) for `register_buffer()` method reads

> This is typically used to register a buffer that should not to be considered a model parameter. For example, BatchNorm’s `running_mean` is not a parameter, but is part of the persistent state.

As you already observed, model *parameters* are learned and updated using SGD during the training process.
However, sometimes there are other quantities that are part of a model's "state" and should be
 - saved as part of `state_dict`.
 - moved to `cuda()` or `cpu()` with the rest of the model's parameters.
 - cast to `float`/`half`/`double` with the rest of the model's parameters.
Registering these "arguments" as the model's `buffer` allows pytorch to track them and save them like regular parameters, but prevents pytorch from updating them using SGD mechanism.

An example for a buffer can be found in [`_BatchNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html#BatchNorm2d) module where the `running_mean` , `running_var` and `num_batches_tracked` are registered as buffers and updated by accumulating statistics of data forwarded through the layer. This is in contrast to `weight` and `bias` parameters that learns an affine transformation of the data using regular SGD optimization.

Comment: This raises the question what is the use case of buffers which are registered via [`register_buffer(name, tensor, persistent=False)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer), i.e., which aren't even part of the `state_dict`?

Comment: @bluenote10 this makes a lot of sense. Suppose you have a constant tensor as part of your `nn.Module` (e.g., position embedding etc.) and you want to make sure this tensor is moved to the appropriate device and cast to the right `dtype` whenever you call `.to()` for you r `nn.Module`...

Answer (score 28):

Both parameters and buffers you create for a module (`nn.Module`).

Say you have a linear layer `nn.Linear`. You already have `weight` and `bias` parameters. But if you need a new parameter you use [`register_parameter()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter) to register a new named parameter that is a tensor.

When you register a new parameter it will appear inside the `module.parameters()` iterator, but when you register a buffer it will not.

> The difference:

[Buffers](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) are named tensors that do not update gradients at every step, like parameters.
For buffers, you create your custom logic (fully up to you).

The good thing is when you save the model, all params and buffers are saved, and when you move the model to or off the CUDA params and buffers will go as well.