# What is a buffer in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I understand what [register_buffer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) does and the difference between [register_buffer and register_parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540745/what-is-the-difference-between-register-parameter-and-register-buffer-in-pytorch).

But what is the precise definition of a buffer in PyTorch?

Comment: 4th paragraph here may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546078/365102

Comment: Sounds like they're just tensors (aka data) that aren't modified during training.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a more specific definition. I.e. is a buffer a tensor with `requires_grad` equal to False?

Comment: @Berriel - I liked your previous answer...

Comment: @luminicentauri the key is that the buffers are registered in another attribute, so they have a different logic. The relevant details can be seen in the links you provided in the question.

Comment: @Berriel - so then to clarify: a buffer is simply a tensor (irrespective of any parameters defined during tensor creation), correct?

Comment: @luminicentauri yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be answered looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5d80f634784d21151f66927c050474f90f377769/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L98-L134):

```py
def register_buffer(self, name, tensor):
    if '_buffers' not in self.__dict__:
        raise AttributeError(
            "cannot assign buffer before Module.__init__() call")
    elif not isinstance(name, torch._six.string_classes):
        raise TypeError("buffer name should be a string. "
                        "Got {}".format(torch.typename(name)))
    elif '.' in name:
        raise KeyError("buffer name can't contain \".\"")
    elif name == '':
        raise KeyError("buffer name can't be empty string \"\"")
    elif hasattr(self, name) and name not in self._buffers:
        raise KeyError("attribute '{}' already exists".format(name))
    elif tensor is not None and not isinstance(tensor, torch.Tensor):
        raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' object to buffer '{}' "
                        "(torch Tensor or None required)"
                        .format(torch.typename(tensor), name))
    else:
        self._buffers[name] = tensor
```

That is, the buffer's name:

- must be a string: `not isinstance(name, torch._six.string_classes)`
- cannot contain a `.` (dot): `'.' in name`
- cannot be an empty string: `name == ''`
- cannot be an attribute of the Module: `hasattr(self, name)`
- should be unique: `name not in self._buffers`

and the `tensor` (guess what?):

- should be a Tensor: `isinstance(tensor, torch.Tensor)`

So, the buffer is just a tensor with these properties, registered in the `_buffers` attribute of a `Module`;