# Certain members of a torch module aren't moved to GPU even if model.to(device) is called

Tags: python, pytorch

An mwe is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model,self).__init__()
        self.mat = torch.randn(2,2)

    def forward(self,x):
        print('self.mat.device is',self.mat.device)
        x = torch.mv(self.mat,x)
        return x

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
m = model()
m.to(device)

x = torch.tensor([2.,1.])
x = x.to(device)

m(x)
```

The output is

```
self.mat.device is cpu
```

and right after that comes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\cudatest.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(m(x))
  File "E:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\cudatest.py", line 11, in forward
    x = torch.mv(self.mat,x)
RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_mv
```

The code works fine if I set `device = torch.device('cpu')`. It seems that the problem is `model.mat` is not moved to GPU even after `m.to(device)` is called. Why doesn't whis work? How can I fix this? Please note the following:

1. Even though this particular example can be fixed by using `self.mat = nn.Linear(2,2)` and `x = self.mat(x)` instead, in my original program, I need a temporary tensor to store some data in `forward()` that is also used in some arithmetics. How can I construct such a tensor and send it to GPU when calling `m.to(device)`
2. It is not known in advance whether the computer has GPU or not. Therefore, writing `self.mat = self.mat.cuda()` is not a good solution for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) apply Module's methods such as `.cpu()`, `.cuda()` and `.to()` only to sub-modules, [parameters](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#parameters) and [buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541778/1714410), but *NOT* to regular class members. pytorch has no way of knowing that `self.mat`, in your case, is an actual tensor that should be moved around.

Once you decide if your `mat` should be a parameter or a buffer, simply register it accordingly, e.g.

```py
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model,self).__init__()
        self.register_buffer(name='mat', tensor=torch.randn(2,2))
```